# Should I lock a whole object in a function modifying a small part of it?

Tags: java, multithreading, locking

I'm beginning with multithreading in Java, and was confronted to the following problem.

Let's say we have **an object containing a collection of integers, and other variables**.

I want to create a function modifying one of the collection's integers.
**Should it lock the whole object, or solely the collection?**

I understand locking the whole object would work, but I'm afraid I'll have a drop in performances if other threads try to access the other variables of my objects.

Comment: If you're beginning with multithreading, you should worry about correctness instead of performance.

Comment: You should synchronize access to all shared mutable state.

Comment: You can make some method synchronized and performance will drop only for this methods. Of cource the parallel calls of other methods for the same object should ensure correctness. If they can't then lock a whole object.

Comment: Well I might have badly formulated it, but I'm asking if it is correct to lock only the collection, or if it can cause conflicts to do so?

Comment: It depends entirely on your other code. You can't "lock an object" per se, so you need to make sure that all the code that accesses the collection does it in a threadsafe way.

Comment: I think I got it, thanks for your replies!

Comment: You are sure to come to grief.  Correctness has to trump performance.  Writing multithreaded code is hard, even for smart people.  Don't be fooled into thinking that you'll skate through.

Comment: You can have a look to the concurrent api proposed by Java: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Should it lock the whole object, or solely the collection?

This will mainly depend on what you actually have in this class. As already mentioned you need to synchronize access to all shared mutable state so here assuming that your whole object is a shared mutable state, you will need indeed to protect any read and write access to any of its fields with an implicit or intrinsic lock.

Now the question is how are those fields linked to each other?

Indeed let's say that your fields are a `List` of carrots and a `List` of cars, they have nothing in common expect being shared mutable lists, in this case you could use one dedicated implicit or intrinsic lock per field.

But if you have for example the rate Euro to Dollar and the rate Dollar to Euro that are directly connected to each other, as you need to ensure the consistency of both fields, you will need to use the same implicit or intrinsic lock for both fields.

So to summarize if all your fields are connected to each other using one implicit or intrinsic lock for all of them will be the way to go otherwise use one dedicated implicit or intrinsic lock per group of fields that are related to each other.

Comment: In my case I do have something like a List of carrots and a List of cars. So if I understood correctly, I could use a set of two different Locks, one for the carrots and one for the cars?

Comment: yes that's the idea, sorry for the stupid example but I think it is easier to understand this way

Comment: No problem, it actually helped me to understand, that's exactly what I was wondering. Thanks a lot!